# Custom Blazor Component not reflecting binding properly

Tags: blazor-server-side, devexpress-blazor

I have a big `DxFormLayout` with many `DxFormLayoutGroup`s and each `DxFormLayoutGroup` has many `DxFormlauoutItem`s. I'm wondering if it is possible to sompress the razor code by componentizing a few `DxFormlauoutItem`s. Here is my code:

**Page:**

```
<EditForm Model="@_model" Context="editFormContext" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />

    <DxFormLayout CssClass="dxFormLayoutHeaderStyle">       
        <DxFormLayoutGroup Caption="Options" ColSpanMd="12">
            <DxFormLayoutItem Caption="" ColSpanMd="12">
                @*The below is repeated multiple times*@
                <Template>
                    <DxStackLayout ItemSpacing="10px">
                        <Items>
                            <DxStackLayoutItem Length="95%">
                                <Template>
                                    <DxTextBox ReadOnly="true" @bind-Text="@_model.TooltipTextForNegotiationsDoneBySupplyManagement"
                                               title="@_model.TooltipTextForNegotiationsDoneBySupplyManagement" SizeMode="SizeMode.Medium"/>
                                </Template>
                            </DxStackLayoutItem>
                            <DxStackLayoutItem Length="5%">
                                <Template>
                                    <div class="stacklayout-item">
                                        <DxCheckBox CheckType="CheckType.Switch" style="width: 100%" @bind-Checked="@_model.IsNegotiationsDoneBySupplyManagement"
                                                    Alignment="CheckBoxContentAlignment.Center" title="@_model.TooltipTextForNegotiationsDoneBySupplyManagement"/>
                                    </div>
                                </Template>
                            </DxStackLayoutItem>
                        </Items>
                    </DxStackLayout>
                </Template >
                @*The above is repeated multiple times*@
            </DxFormLayoutItem >
        </DxFormLayoutGroup>            
    </DxFormLayout>
</EditForm>

@*The below become a component with parameters and bindings*@

<EditForm Model="@_model" Context="editFormContext" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />

    <DxFormLayout CssClass="dxFormLayoutHeaderStyle">       
        <DxFormLayoutItem Caption="" ColSpanMd="12">
            <Template>
                <BudgetReleaseRequestDecisionPoint DecisionText="@_model.TooltipTextForNegotiationsDoneBySupplyManagement"
                                                   DecisionResult="@_model.IsNegotiationsDoneBySupplyManagement" />
            </Template >
        </DxFormLayoutItem >            
    </DxFormLayout>
</EditForm>
```

**Component:**

```
<style>
    .stacklayout-item {
        text-align: center;
        height: 100%;
        padding-top: 6px;
    }
</style>

<DxStackLayout ItemSpacing="10px">
    <Items>
        <DxStackLayoutItem Length="95%">
            <Template>
                <DxTextBox ReadOnly="true" @bind-Text="@DecisionText" title="@DecisionText" SizeMode="SizeMode.Medium"/>
            </Template>
        </DxStackLayoutItem>
        <DxStackLayoutItem Length="5%">
            <Template>
                <div class="stacklayout-item">
                    <DxCheckBox CheckType="CheckType.Switch" style="width: 100%" @bind-Checked="@DecisionResult"
                                Alignment="CheckBoxContentAlignment.Center" title="@DecisionResult"/>
                </div>
            </Template>
        </DxStackLayoutItem>
    </Items>
</DxStackLayout>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string DecisionText
    {
        get => _decisionText;
        set
        {
            if (_decisionText == value) return;

            _decisionText = value;
            DecisionTextChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
        }
    }

    [Parameter]
    public bool DecisionResult
    {
        get => _decisionResult;
        set
        {
            if (_decisionResult == value) return;

            _decisionResult = value;
            DecisionResultChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
        }
    }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> DecisionTextChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<bool> DecisionResultChanged { get; set; }

    private string _decisionText;
    private bool _decisionResult;
}
```

**Issue:**

I made it a razor component but I'm having issue as the model's properties are not getting updated on the main page. I can confirm this by one property: On the page, there is a `SpinEdit` that get enabled once `model.IsNegotiationsDoneBySupplyManagement` is set to true. That is not happening anymore once I went to component-mode:

```
<DxSpinEdit Id="amountSavedAfterNegotiations" @bind-Value="@_model.SavingsAfterNegotiations" Enabled="@_model.IsNegotiationsDoneBySupplyManagement" title="Savings (AED) after negotiations?" />
```

When I had the original code (without component/top-most code I pasted), togeling this checkbox would toggle the `Enabled` state of the `SpinEdit`. After I transferred to component, the `Enabled` state is not longer sensing changes to the `model`'s property leading me to believe the `model`'s properties on the page are not getting updated.

What is wrong with the way I wired the component?

Comment: Currently reading https://blazor-university.com/components/two-way-binding/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing magic was on the Page where I was calling the components. This is what I was doing:

```
<BudgetReleaseRequestDecisionPoint DecisionText="@_model.TooltipTextForNegotiationsDoneBySupplyManagement" DecisionResult="@_model.IsNegotiationsDoneBySupplyManagement" />
```

This is the correct syntax:

```
<BudgetReleaseRequestDecisionPoint DecisionText="@_model.TooltipTextForNegotiationsDoneBySupplyManagement" @bind-DecisionResult="@_model.IsNegotiationsDoneBySupplyManagement" />
```

I had to change the `DecisionResult` to `@bind-DecisionResult`. Now the `Page`'s `model` is reflecting the changes that occur to its properties with in component.